# onActivityResult() works weird

Tags: java, android

First of all, this is not a problem about getting results from an Activity.

I've this code:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent pData)
        {
     if ( requestCode == CODIGO_RESPUESTA )
           {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK )            {
            final String dato =  pData.getExtras().getString("valorid");//Obtengo el string de la subactividad
            Target =  pData.getExtras().getString("valorSujeto");
            String a=Target;
            id=Long.parseLong(dato);
            Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, here's the problem: The Reset() function works if called everwhere in the code, but fails when it's called from this onActivityResult()

When I say it fails, I mean weird things happen: Reset() is a function which manages a Chronometer, and preset it to determinates values. Reset() used in everywhere in the code results in a correct reset of Chronometer. But called from onActivityResults, it's futile.

I'm totally newbie in Java/Android programming, but I've been looking for this question and I've not found anything.

I'd appreciate your help, thank you!

Edit: Reset()

```
    public void ResetCrono() {
           TimeRef=timeWhenStopped;
           Cronometro.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped+offsetTotalms);
           CronometroParcial.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timeWhenStoppedRelative +offsetTotalms);
           Cronometro.start();
           Cronometro.stop();
           CronometroParcial.start();
           CronometroParcial.stop();
          }
```

Comment: so that is issue inside Reset() isn't it? Reset() has something which is not there when onActivityResult() is called?

Comment: " I mean weird things happen" means what? Does the function not run or you get unexpected results?

Comment: The function runs, but the Chrono doesnt get reset. I'm going to edit the question to post reset() function.

Comment: why don't you post Reset() code and a lil' bit of Chronometer part?

Comment: Then I think you need to post that function

Comment: are you sure that you used `setResult(Result_OK)` then `finish();` in the activity that was called with the code `CODIGO_RESPUESTA`, please make a `TOAST` in the second `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, and I've debugged and the Reset() is launched. I've stepped into the function and I've not seen any errors. I think something happens when onActivityResults() finishes

Answer (score 0):

your chronometer is probably interrupted by the the `onStop()` method of your activity. whateever calls onActivityResult will also force the onStop method to run. To test this theory put `reset()` in the onResume() method of your activity and when you run your activity, press the home button on your android device, and then go back into the app (by going into recently open apps, not by pressing the launcher again)

Reset() will get called, and this will help you narrow down what happened, or you can see if the chronometer is working as expected

I could also be completely incorrect, but I'll take that chance

Comment: I have tried something like you say: I used a button which launches ResetCrono(); and it works. I think I need ResetCrono(); to be called from main activity, and not from onActivityResult. It's possible to do that in some way?

Comment: @user2544040 you can call ResetChrono() in the onPause() before you the next activity runs (which calls onActivityResult in your main activity)

Comment: But I need the value returned by the subactivity in order to pre-set the Chrono, so I'm afraid I cant use onPause() :(